# Angular 7 - No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm getting this error on my Angular 7 app and I don't know why. Even with some researches it seems that this error doesn't make sense.

This is what I have:

```
<mat-form-field>
     <input matInput placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="data.name" [disabled]="inputReadonly" ngDefaultControl > 
</mat-form-field>
```

I've tried with and withoud ngDefaultControl on mat-form-field and/or input, with and without the name attribute and to move [(ngModel)] on input. Nothing is changed, I'm still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 7):

`ngModel` has to be specified on the `input`, not on the `mat-form-field`. The only purpose of `mat-form-field` is to apply some Material CSS

Comment: Moving [(ngModel)] on the input doesn't change anything. I've tried to move it on mat-form-field to see if the error disappear. Btw I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputModule` imported in your `app.module.ts` and also declared in `@NgModule({... imports:[MatFormFieldModule,MatInputModule, ...],...}`